# QUIC with HTTP 1

Tags: android, http2, http-1.1, quic, cronet

Can I use QUIC with HTTP 1 (in Android).
I have been reading that QUIC works with HTTP 2 but when I used it with HTTP 1 then my HTTP connection time improved.

I was using

```
urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

after QUIC it is:

```
 val engine: CronetEngine =
            engineBuilder.enableHttp2(true).enableBrotli(true).enableQuic(true).enableHttpCache(
                CronetEngine.Builder.HTTP_CACHE_IN_MEMORY,
                (100 * 1024).toLong()
            ).build()

 val stream: StreamHandler =
            StreamHandlerFactory(engine).createURLStreamHandler("https") as StreamHandler
 val urlConnection: HttpURLConnection = stream.openConnection(url) as HttpURLConnection

inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream()
```

I want to understand why connection time reduced with **Quic + HTTP 1** if QUIC only supports HTTP 2

Comment: hm...I'm not sure how cornet works, but I see a `enableHttp2(true)` in your code. Why you say you are using QUIC in HTTP1?

Comment: I tried it to reduce connection time (i.e getting an object of input stream from url connection object). Although I enable HTTP2 but the api call that I am making is on HTTP 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Answering late here, but Cronet natively supports HTTP, HTTP/2, HTTP/3 over Quic protocols. This is the same library used to power YouTube and other apps - you can read about it in detail here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/cronet

You are technically using UDP, and HTTP/1 is over it.